# markedjs from React component - stopped capturing the headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

Strange problem with marked executed within my React component.

Has been working, but cannot see why it's stopped.

This is my React component

```
** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var marked = require('marked');
var Panel = require('react-bootstrap').Panel;
var Highlight = require('highlight.js');
var Markdown = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount:function( ){

        marked.setOptions({
            highlight: function (code) {
                return Highlight.highlightAuto(code).value;
            },
            sanitize: true
        });
    },
    render: function () {

        var rawMarkup;
        if (_.isString(this.props.content)) {
            rawMarkup = marked(this.props.content);
        }
        else if (_.isArray(this.props.content)) {
            rawMarkup = marked(this.props.content.join("\n"));
        }
         return (
              <div>
                 <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawMarkup}} />
              </div>
         );      
    }
});

exports.Markdown = Markdown;
```

Tracing it through, the problem appear to lie here:
(this is extract of marked js)

```
// heading
    if (cap = this.rules.heading.exec(src)) {
      src = src.substring(cap[0].length);
      this.tokens.push({
        type: 'heading',
        depth: cap[1].length,
        text: cap[2]
      });
      continue;
    }
```

Where `this.rules.heading` == `/^ *(#{1,6}) +([^\n]+?) *#* *(?:\n+|$)/`
and `src` == "#heading"

Nothing is found.

I have updated npm packages, but don't see how this would have stopped working?

Any ideas?

Comment: very strange, the current source for marked has headers regex as `/^ *(#{1,6}) *([^\n]+?) *#* *(?:\n+|$)/` which is different

Comment: now discovered to be due to the options.gfm being true by default in 0.3.5